# Loading multiple images with Ipython display in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to use The Ipython library to display some PNGs I have stored in another folder. Usually all I have to do is:

```
from IPython.display import Image
img = 'images/giraffe.png'
Image(url=img)
```

and that will display the giraffe. However, If I try to load up 2 images within a cell, it will just load the image that was last called.

```
from IPython.display import Image
img1 = 'images/giraffe.png'
Image(url=img1)

img2 = 'images/monkey.png'
Image(url=img2)
```

If I do that, all that will load is the png of the monkey.

I tried doing it with Matplotlib, but that adds x and y-axis ticks to the png, which is not appropriate for this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using combination of `Image` and `display`?

```
from IPython.display import display, Image

i1 = Image("images/giraffe.png")
i2 = Image('images/monkey.png')

display(i1, i2)
```

[`display` docs](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/api/generated/IPython.display.html#IPython.display.display)

Answer (score 0):

I found answer from Kamil Niski  to be so helpful, that I felt I should contribute my extensions to the original answer. Thank you.

### Snippet of Python

```
import IPython.display
image_files=["c:/sample1.png", "c:/sample2.png"]
for image_file in image_files:
    img= IPython.display.Image(image_file)
    IPython.display.display(f"Going to display image: {image_file}")
    IPython.display.display(img)
```

### Output in Jupyter

[image]

Comment: Since right now there's only two answers, it is obvious which answer you mean; however, that may not always be the case. And so you may want add mention of Kamil Niski's name to your extension of it. Or add a link.